# How to handle useEffect being called twice in strictMode for things that should only be run once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I understand that React calls useEffect twice in strict mode, this question is about asking what the correct way of handling it is.

I have recently hit an issue with `React` `useEffect` being called twice in `strictMode`. I'd like to keep strict mode to avoid issues, but I don't see any good way of making sure some specific effects are only run once. This is in a `next.js` environment, where I specifically want the code to only run in the client once.

For example, given the following component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ky from "ky";

const NeedsToRunOnce: React.FC = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const doSomethingThatOnlyShouldHappenOnce = (data: any) => {
    // Do something with the loaded data that should only happen once
    console.log(`This log appears twice!`, data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loading) return;
    console.log("This happens twice despite trying to set loading to true");
    setLoading(true);
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const data = await ky.get("/data/json_data_2000.json").json();
      setLoading(false);
      doSomethingThatOnlyShouldHappenOnce(data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return <div></div>;
};

export default NeedsToRunOnce;
```

`useEffect` will be called twice, and both times `loading` will still be false. This is because `strictMode` makes it be called twice with the same state. The request will go through twice, and call `doSomethingThatOnlyShouldHappenOnce` twice. All the `console.log` calls above will appear twice in the console.

Since I can't modify the state to let my component know that the request has already started happening, how can I stop the get request from happening twice and then calling code that I *only* want to be called once? (For context, I am initialising an external library with the data loaded in the `useEffect`, and this library should only be initialised once).

I found a [GitHub issue about this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24455) where Dan Abramov says:

> Usually you’d want to have some kind of cleanup for your effect. It should either cancel your fetch or make sure you ignore its result by setting a variable inside your effect. Once you do this, there should be no actual difference in behavior.

> If you cancel your fetch in effect cleanup, only one request will complete in development. However, it also doesn’t matter if another request fires. It’s being ignored anyway, and the stress-testing only happens in development.

While I agree in principle, this is tedious in practice. I've already hit two different use cases in my application where I have some library call or request that needs to only be done once in the client.

What's a reliable way of making sure that a piece of code in `useEffect` is only run once here? Using a state to keep track of it having already been run doesn't help, since `react` calls the component twice with the same state in a row.

Comment: Your effect's dependency array is empty, but your effect reads `loading`, so it must also depend on it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a ref to execute your useEffect once (first time or second time, as you wish), or just use a customHook. In my case, i execute the useEffect the second time. Swap true and false, to execute it the first time and not the second one.

```js
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function useEffectOnce(fn: () => void) {
  const ref = useRef(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      fn();
    }
    return () => {
      ref.current = true;
    };
  }, [fn]);
}
```

And to use it, you can pass your callback function in param :

```js
useEffectOnce(() => console.log("hello"));
```

Comment: We shouldn't use those technics and prefer optimizing useEffect with clean-ups, request caching... As the behavior is there for a good reason, we should deal with it correctly instead of avoiding it. For a more detailed answer, you can visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/useeffect-is-running-twice-on-mount-in-react